# Parsing/Iterating over Json

Tags: c#, json, json.net

I'm fairly new to parsing Json with C# and i'm having a little issue i can't work my head around.

My data looks something like this:

```
{
    "languages": {
        "ja_lang": {
            "data": {
                "name": "Japanese"
            },
            "files": [["ja",
            "Japanese File",
            "lang_ja.txt"]]
        },
        "en_lang": {
            "data": {
                "name": "English"
            },
            "files": [["en",
            "English File",
            "lang_en.txt"]]
        }
    }
}
```

Now i want to iterate over the items in languages and only work with the one where the object-name starts with "ja_" (in this case it would only work with "ja_lang" and ignore "en_lang"), then extract the name inside data and the "lang_ja.txt" in files.

To Parse the Json in C# i downloaded the Newtonsoft.Json library and came up with this:

```
dynamic json_obj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject("json string");

// when debugging language holds { "ja_lang": { "data": { "name": "Japanese" }, "files": [["ja", "Japanese File", "lang_ja.txt"]] } }
foreach (var language in json_obj.languages)
{
    // not sure how i can access the object-name
    /*if(!language.StartsWith("ja_"))
        continue;*/

    // Exception: 'Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JProperty' does not contain a definition for 'data' - Not sure why it is treated as a property?
    var name = language.data.name;
    var file = language.files[2];
}
```

I'm sorry for this probably dumb question, but i've been trying to cast it to different types and searched the web for solutions, but i just couldn't figure it out. So if someone could help me out with this i would be really greatful.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You're stating in a comment on the now deleted answer that you cannot use a model because the format changes, but you've still fixed the path to `files` which you expect to be an array, and you've fixed the path to `name`, which is inside `data`, how much of this is really going to change?

Comment: @LasseVågsætherKarlsen the snippet i posted i just an snippet of a larger dataset with lots more properties and i dont want to have hundreds of classes just to extract this little piece of data. Also i fixed the paths, because they don't change, the only thing in languages that changes is the amount of language objects, but they are all structured the same.

Comment: OK, but bear in mind that we can only answer the questions you ask, if you have. If, say, you now comment on my answer with "yes, but, this other type I didn't mention cannot be used like this" then there is simply no way we can provide a general solution to a general problem if all you've given us is a specific problem.

Comment: @LasseVågsætherKarlsen yes, i think i should've worded it better. Anyway your answer fits perfectly for what i needed, so my problem is resolved! Thanks for your time and effort, it's much appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you're stating in a comment (on an answer that has been deleted) that the data changes so a fixed model won't work, you can still fix what is known:

Here's a [LINQPad](http://linqpad.net) program that demonstrates:

```
void Main()
{
    var collection = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<LanguagesCollection>(File.ReadAllText(@"c:\temp\test.json"));
    foreach (var keyValuePair in collection.Languages)
        if (keyValuePair.Key.StartsWith("ja_"))
            keyValuePair.Value.Dump();

}

public class LanguagesCollection
{
    public Dictionary<string, JObject> Languages { get; } = new Dictionary<string, JObject>();
}
```

This will deserialize the outer object, with the `"languages"` key, and inside you have a dictionary with the keys, `"ja_lang", "en_lang"`, and you can just process the values as you see fit. These are left as `JObject` which means they will contain whatever json was present as a value for that key in the dictionary.

Comment: Works perfectly! Exactly what i've been looking for. Thanks alot :)

Answer (score 0):

Using a site like [json2sharp](http://json2csharp.com/) you can just pass your json data in and get a ready to use c# model out.

Then you can easily deserialize your json data into that c# model and use the properties for much easier handling:

```
            string jsonData = @"{
                                'languages': {
                                    'ja_lang': {
                                        'data': {
                                            'name': 'Japanese'
                                        },
                                        'files': [['ja',
                                        'Japanese File',
                                        'lang_ja.txt']]
                                    },
                                    'en_lang': {
                                        'data': {
                                            'name': 'English'
                                        },
                                        'files': [['en',
                                        'English File',
                                        'lang_en.txt']]
                                    }
                                }
                            }";

        RootObject data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(jsonData);


        foreach(Languages lang in data.languages) //would work if Languages was a listing
        {

        }
```

Although I admit that your Json is a bit strange and that Languages most likly should be a listing and not a property for each language.

Comment: Not necessarily a property, could be a dictionary which looks like an object full of keys with the same value type but different names.

Comment: Ye, but the amout of languages changes and other properties are possible to exist, that's why i didnt want to deserialize it as a class, since it's members arent always certain, i'm more looking for somethig dynamic that extracts only the data i want. The json data i supplied is only a little snippet from a larger dataset

Comment: If you define objects with only those properties you want, any leftover json will be ignored (it will be syntax-checked to ensure deserialization knows what to deserialize, but the data will be thrown out). Wouldn't this be an option? If you have dynamic areas you can use `JObject` to reserve a space for them but leave their actual format dynamic until runtime.

Comment: @LasseVågsætherKarlsen Oh i thought i had to fully map it out, this could've worked as well then, but your answer suits my need better in that regard, but i will definitely try this out if i want to deserialize json to a class in the future!